# Why is my object update executed twice for the MagicalRecord persistent store?

Tags: core-data, ios7, magicalrecord

I've added the latest MagicalRecord develop branch code (eb72053) to a new XCode 5.0.2 Empty project w/ Core Data.

I created the following simple model for a Person:

[image: Person Object Model]

Then, in addition to creating the NSManagedObject subclass `Person` and adding the MagicalRecord import to my .pch file, I set my application delegate to be the following:

```
#import "MRFAppDelegate.h"
#import "Person.h"

@implementation MRFAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self dataTests];
    return YES;
}

- (void)dataTests {
    [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithStoreNamed:@"MagicalRecordFunTests.sqlite"];

    Person *person = [Person findFirst];
    if (!person) {
        NSLog(@"Could not find person");
        person = [Person createEntity];
    }

    NSLog(@"currentAge: %@", person.age);
    person.age = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[person.age integerValue] + 10];
    NSLog(@"newAge: %@", person.age);

    person.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, and now I am %@", person.name, person.age];

    [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];

    exit(0);
}

@end
```

Now, when I run this for the first time, I see the following expected output in the console:

```
2014-02-04 03:12:50.602 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWithStoreCoordinator:](0x4ff0ac) -> Created Context UNNAMED
2014-02-04 03:12:50.604 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setRootSavingContext:](0x4ff0ac) Set Root Saving Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8d1dc90>
2014-02-04 03:12:50.605 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_newMainQueueContext](0x4ff0ac) Created Main Queue Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8a0e290>
2014-02-04 03:12:50.605 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] +[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_setDefaultContext:](0x4ff0ac) Set Default Context: <NSManagedObjectContext: 0x8a0e290>
2014-02-04 03:12:50.608 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] Could not find person
2014-02-04 03:12:50.609 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] currentAge: 0
2014-02-04 03:12:50.610 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] newAge: 10
2014-02-04 03:12:50.610 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x8a0e290) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x8a0e290): *** DEFAULT ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
2014-02-04 03:12:50.611 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x8a0e290) → Save Parents? 1
2014-02-04 03:12:50.612 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x8a0e290) → Save Synchronously? 1
2014-02-04 03:12:50.612 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x8a0e290) Context DEFAULT is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 1 inserted objects
2014-02-04 03:12:50.614 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x8d1dc90) → Saving <NSManagedObjectContext (0x8d1dc90): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
2014-02-04 03:12:50.615 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x8d1dc90) → Save Parents? 1
2014-02-04 03:12:50.615 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x8d1dc90) → Save Synchronously? 1
2014-02-04 03:12:50.616 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalRecord) MR_contextWillSave:](0x8d1dc90) Context BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) is about to save. Obtaining permanent IDs for new 1 inserted objects
2014-02-04 03:12:50.618 MagicalRecordFun[24299:70b] __70-[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:]_block_invoke25(0x8d1dc90) → Finished saving: <NSManagedObjectContext (0x8d1dc90): *** BACKGROUND SAVING (ROOT) ***> on *** MAIN THREAD ***
```

However, if I open up the newly created .sqlite file, I see unexpected data, which looks like each update I made to the model was called twice:

```
sqlite> select ZAGE,ZNAME from ZPERSON;
20|(null), and now I am 10, and now I am 20
```

Each time I run the app subsequently, it does the same thing, picking up the unexpected value from the database, and then adding 10 to the age on the model object, but adding 20 to the age in the database.

Comment: I also see the same behavior when using master (7f5142c, v2.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @casademora points out, MagicalRecord is behaving correctly in this situation. The issue here is the `exit(0)`, which causes the iOS Simulator to call `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` a second time.

Moving this example code to `main.m` or changing the `exit(0)` to `exit(1)` gives the correct behavior.

Answer (score 1):

What this looks like to me is that you're running this test app over and over again and it's simply concatenating the name as you're specifying this line of code:

```
person.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, and now I am %@", person.name, person.age];
```

Since you only have one record (one row in your sqlite data) in your data output, this seems like correct behavior to me.

Comment: The correct behavior would be to concatenate it once per run. It's getting concatenated twice per run, just like how the age is being added twice per each run.

Comment: with the first "name" being (null), you are actually getting 3 concatenations.

Comment: The first concat is `(null)` to `", and now I am 10"`, and that is expected since it's a newly created object. The second concat is `(null), and now I am 10` to `, and now I am 20`, and I have no idea where that's coming from (the debugger only breaks once on the `person.name =` line.

Comment: Are you running a test project, i.e. one that is unit tested? If so, you are likely running this method twice, once in applicationDidFinishLaunch, and again in the test

Comment: I wasn't running the generated tests, but just to be sure, I deleted the generated test case as well as the default test target. Deleted the app, did a clean build, still same issue. Is it reproducible or is there something wonky with my build tools?